# How to make my discord bot only work in a chat?

Tags: discord.js

I am using discord.js to implement a bot in the discord. When I use a command in any channel in my server, my bot responds to it, but I would like that my bot only worked if someone was sending the commands inside a private chat with the bot, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want it to work between DMs, do

```js
if (!message.channel.type == `dm`) return;

//other commands
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the message was sent in a certain channel by checking the [`Message.channel.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=id) property.

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.channel.id !== "ChannelID") return false;

    // Execute your commands here
});
```